# Get wifi access point location in android

Tags: android, gps, location, wifi, point

Is there a way to get the Location (latitude, longitude) of an wifi access point? I need to display them on a map so the only way for me to do that is to get the location of each wifi access point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a database of access points for this, such as [the one at WiGLE.net](http://www.wigle.net/).

Contact them for information on a commercial license.

Answer (score 1):

Routers don't typically have GPS capabilities. You can determine the geographic location roughly using a reverse IP lookup and a geographic ISP database.

You might be able to estimate a distance away from the user using signal strength...

Comment: Signal strength is not remotely appropriate for getting distance.  I could put an AP 10 miles from you and give you the same signal as one 200ft. away.  If you have a collection of signal strength readings from several points, you can begin to estimate location.